# Matching attribute name ending by string in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know about those three type of selector in CSS: `[att^=val] [att$=val] [att*=val]` to select an element having an attribute **value** containing, ending or starting with a string. What I want to know is if there is a way to select an element having an attribute **name** containing a string ?

For example, to select all angulars attribute, I would write `*[ng-*]{/*CSS rules*/}`

EDIT:
It seems that I didn't get understood...
Let's say I have this HTML:

```
<a class="button" ng-click="doSmth()">execute</a>
<p class="button" data-ng-click="doSmth()">execute</p>
```

Now I want to select all elements having an attribute **name AND NOT his value** containing ng-click.

What I'm doing right now is

```
*[ng-click], *[data-ng-click]{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Is there a way of doing so without writing every single possibility.
Maybe something like

```
*[*ng-click]{/*ALL elements having an attribute name starting with ANY string then ending with 'ng-click'*/
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: `name` as `<a name="someName">` or `name` as tag name?

Comment: `[att^=val] [att$=val] [att*=val]` it's the same that you are asking. Are you sure that you know about this kind of selectors? Remember `[attr="value"]`

Comment: @Justinas , with your code: `<a name="someName">`, to me the attribute name is 'name', the attribute value is 'someName' and the tag name is 'a'

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I'm not sure you understood what I'm looking for, I've edited the question to be clearer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use something like this.

**HTML**

```
<p name="para1">text</p>
```

**CSS**

```
[name=para1] { color: red; }
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I'm looking for, I've edited the question to be clearer, I'm not trying to select following the attribute value, but his own name